# Destructuring references for Iterator::find in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm reading Rust by Example and having trouble with [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/fn/closures/closure_examples/iter_find.html) on searching through iterators.

```
pub trait Iterator {
    // The type being iterated over.
    type Item;

    // `find` takes `&mut self` meaning the caller may be borrowed
    // and modified, but not consumed.
    fn find<P>(&mut self, predicate: P) -> Option<Self::Item> where
        // `FnMut` meaning any captured variable may at most be
        // modified, not consumed. `&Self::Item` states it takes
        // arguments to the closure by reference.
        P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool {}
}

fn main() {
    let vec1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let vec2 = vec![4, 5, 6];

    // `iter()` for vecs yields `&i32`.
    let mut iter = vec1.iter();
    // `into_iter()` for vecs yields `i32`.
    let mut into_iter = vec2.into_iter();

    // `iter()` for vecs yields `&i32`, and we want to reference one of its
    // items, so we have to destructure `&&i32` to `i32`
    println!("Find 2 in vec1: {:?}", iter     .find(|&&x| x == 2));
    // `into_iter()` for vecs yields `i32`, and we want to reference one of
    // its items, so we have to destructure `&i32` to `i32`
    println!("Find 2 in vec2: {:?}", into_iter.find(| &x| x == 2));
}
```

If `iter()` yields `&i32` and `Iterator::find` takes `&mut self`, why do we need 2 ampersands `&&x` instead of one `&x`? And for that matter why isn't it `&mut x`, which would match the function's signature?

Similarly, if `into_iter()` yields `i32` and `Iterator::find` takes `&mut self`, why don't we write `&mut x` instead of `&x` between the pipes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `find()` takes `&mut self` is not relevant. It means *the iterator* needs to be mutably borrowed, i.e. `iter.find(f)` is actually `Iterator::find(&mut iter, f)`.

The `|&&x|`/`|&x|` is for the callback, which its type is `F where F: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool`. `Self::Item` is `&i32` for `iter` and `i32` for `into_iter`, so we end with `&&i32` and `&i32`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared things up for me. But I think you mean `Self::Item` is `i32` for `into_iter`.